# Orbital period from TLE data

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, orbital-elements

Is there a way to calculate the orbital period from the Two Line Element (TLE) data?

Comment: yes (obviously). use the mean motion field

Comment: Hi @McMissile you can find the answer to your question in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/35190/12102). I've voted to close your question as a duplicate because that answer answers your question. Don't worry, it's not the end of the world, your question will continue to help others find that answer. Feel free to ask more questions! You also have the option of modifying this question, but in this case it seems such a good fit that duping might be the best choice.